# Neutron damage in HPGe detectors (or any semiconductor)

Tags: semiconductor-physics, particle-detectors

From what I understand, neutrons hitting a high purity germanium (HPGe) detector will cause damage to it by displacing atoms from the lattice, thus creating vacancies which become a trap for charge carriers.

These vacancies in turn, broaden the peak in an unsymmetrical way.

The question is, why does this cause a broadening of the peak? (Both to the left and right of the original peak)

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: It's "high-purity germanium," but honestly that's less identifiable than HPGe.

Answer (score 0):

One just sees a broader peak with some asymmetry. The energy scaling is redone frequently, one does not generally keep track of how it changes over time. But it expected to decrease.

Comment: This is true as far as it goes, but it doesn't really answer the question asked (which is *"Why does the damage manifest in that way?"*, rather than *"How do you manage the equipment while this happens?"*)

Comment: @dmckee My answer points out that the question contains a statement ("to the right of the original peak") for which there is no support.

Comment: Of course there is support, see e.g., http://i.imgur.com/I6MDAqb.png The peak in a damaged detector is clearly asymmetrical, and work has been done about measuring the damage. I've yet to find work explaining this, just measuring it. (Taken from: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/289476515_Neutron_damage_in_mechanically-cooled_high-purity_germanium_detectors_for_field-portable_Prompt_Gamma_Neutron_Activation_analysis_PGNAA_systems)

Comment: I have not read the article, but I assume that the energy scale was recalibrated between these two traces. When the detector gets damaged, the height of the electrical pulses for a certain gamma energy (say 1332 keV) become much smaller and their distribution becomes a bit wider. Then one recalibrates the energy scale of the histogram. Which makes some intensity end up to the right of where it was before. But one should not conclude that any electrical pulses for the 1332 keV gamma gained more voltage.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this, just noticed that asymmetrical curve reminds me a lot avalanche process characteristics.